# Accessing a normalised array and excluding 0 values in a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am accessing X and Y values from a normalized array. But want to exclude  values with 0 while I use the for loop to apply an equation to every bin of the normalised array. I am getting errors with the 0 values.

```
     normed = array([[ 0.0003,  0.0026,  0.0149,  0.0288,  0.0328,  0.0174,  0.0036,
     0.0004,  0.    ,  0.    ],
   [ 0.0001,  0.0024,  0.0103,  0.0244,  0.0321,  0.0211,  0.0064,
     0.0006,  0.    ,  0.    ],
   [ 0.0003,  0.0012,  0.0072,  0.0235,  0.0325,  0.0246,  0.0079,
     0.0012,  0.    ,  0.    ],
   [ 0.    ,  0.0008,  0.0065,  0.0182,  0.0346,  0.0274,  0.0124,
     0.002 ,  0.0004,  0.    ],
   [ 0.    ,  0.0005,  0.0033,  0.0155,  0.0302,  0.0327,  0.0153,
     0.0032,  0.0003,  0.    ],
   [ 0.    ,  0.0002,  0.0025,  0.0121,  0.0283,  0.0342,  0.0184,
     0.0054,  0.0004,  0.    ],
   [ 0.    ,  0.0001,  0.0016,  0.008 ,  0.0253,  0.0318,  0.0219,
     0.0084,  0.001 ,  0.0002],
   [ 0.    ,  0.    ,  0.0008,  0.0056,  0.0198,  0.0316,  0.0296,
     0.0108,  0.0018,  0.0002],
   [ 0.    ,  0.0001,  0.0007,  0.0035,  0.0169,  0.0329,  0.0318,
     0.0163,  0.0039,  0.0006],
   [ 0.    ,  0.    ,  0.0001,  0.0022,  0.0107,  0.0253,  0.0329,
     0.0171,  0.004 ,  0.0011]])

    Px = normed.sum(axis=0)
    array([ 0.0007,  0.0079,  0.0479,  0.1418,  0.2632,  0.279 ,  0.1802,
    0.0654,  0.0118,  0.0021])

    def funct():
    CEnt = 0
        for i in range(0,10):
             if i > 0:
                 for j in range(0,10):
                     if j > 0:
                     CEnt += normed[i][j]*np.log2(Px/(normed[i][j]))
        return CEnt
```

When I print the funct(), I get [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan] with errors:
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply

How can I write a for loop to loop over the 100 bins in the array with the CEnt equation while excluding the 0 values? Thank you very much....

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the indices to zero instead of the actual values.
Following code will just ignore the zeros.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array

normed = array([[ 0.0003,  0.0026,  0.0149,  0.0288,  0.0328,  0.0174,  0.0036,
     0.0004,  0.    ,  0.    ],
   [ 0.0001,  0.0024,  0.0103,  0.0244,  0.0321,  0.0211,  0.0064,
     0.0006,  0.    ,  0.    ],
   [ 0.0003,  0.0012,  0.0072,  0.0235,  0.0325,  0.0246,  0.0079,
     0.0012,  0.    ,  0.    ],
   [ 0.    ,  0.0008,  0.0065,  0.0182,  0.0346,  0.0274,  0.0124,
     0.002 ,  0.0004,  0.    ],
   [ 0.    ,  0.0005,  0.0033,  0.0155,  0.0302,  0.0327,  0.0153,
     0.0032,  0.0003,  0.    ],
   [ 0.    ,  0.0002,  0.0025,  0.0121,  0.0283,  0.0342,  0.0184,
     0.0054,  0.0004,  0.    ],
   [ 0.    ,  0.0001,  0.0016,  0.008 ,  0.0253,  0.0318,  0.0219,
     0.0084,  0.001 ,  0.0002],
   [ 0.    ,  0.    ,  0.0008,  0.0056,  0.0198,  0.0316,  0.0296,
     0.0108,  0.0018,  0.0002],
   [ 0.    ,  0.0001,  0.0007,  0.0035,  0.0169,  0.0329,  0.0318,
     0.0163,  0.0039,  0.0006],
   [ 0.    ,  0.    ,  0.0001,  0.0022,  0.0107,  0.0253,  0.0329,
     0.0171,  0.004 ,  0.0011]])

Px = normed.sum(axis=0)

def funct():
    CEnt = 0
    for line in normed:
         for value in line:
             if value > 0:
                CEnt += value*np.log2(Px/(value))
    return CEnt

print(funct())
```

The loop is (for this 10x10 array) the same as this:

```
def funct():
    CEnt = 0
    for i in range(10):
         for j in range(10):
             if normed[i][j] > 0:
                CEnt += normed[i][j]*np.log2(Px/(normed[i][j]))
    return CEnt
```

Comment: But if I code 'for i in normed'. Does that make all values in my array into i? and then I pick out the zeros while the remaining values are j. So I will be applying the equation to all values except 0, but I am not applying the equation to the normed[i][j] bin? or is every value = normed[i][j] ? Sorry, I am a beginner in Python but somehow ended signing up for something complicated...

Comment: `for i in normed` iterates over the lines of your array `normed`. In every iteration `i` will be an array of 10 values. `for j in i` will then iterate over those values. So `j` is the same as `normed[i][j]` in your code. I renamed the variables in the answer to make this clearer.